# VBScript, is there a way to check Subscript out of Range?

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, outofrangeexception

I am getting an error that says: Subscript out of range: '[number: 8]'

I just want to add something like this:

```
//if not RowArray(8) out of range then
// kill yourself at RowArray(8)
//else
// kill yourself now
//end if
```

The killing part is a joke :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhx59d0t%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and [LBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65s334te%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) will let you determine if a given index is a valid choice within a VBScript array.

```
function GetNumberEight
  If UBound(RowArray) > 8 Then
    GetNumberEight = ""
  else
    GetNumberEight = RowArray(8)
  end if
end function
```

If you need to specifically get one number from an array, though, you may want to consider refactoring your code.  Eight variable declarations, or eight properties of a data object, will not run significantly slower than an eight member array.

(And if it's VB.NET, consider using the other .NET collection classes.)

Comment: @DougM - the condition is wrong, a function returning a number or a string is an abomination, using 'numbered variables' instead of a collecting is a design flaw, neither a variable nor another collection will spare the check whether there is a usable value: -1.

Comment: -1 is a number, not a "no number found."  That's what null (and Nothing) is for.  

And, yeah, don't design arrays this way.  Even in VB Script you have a `Scripting.Dictionary` available.